# Performance for vs. select

Tags: performance, linq, select, for-loop

I read in Bill Wagners Book "Effective C#" that one should favor more declarative *select* statements over traditional loops (*for*).

For example:

```
 int[] foo = new int[1000];
 for (int i = 0; i < foo.Length; i++)
     foo[i] = i * i;
```

is traditional imperative code, whereas this would be declarative Linq code:

```
 int[] foo2 = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 1000)
               select i * i).ToArray();
```

Being an old-fashioned programmer, I prefer the first version.

The question is how about performance? I suppose the first version is also faster.

Comment: OK folks. Instead if voting my own answwer down, tell me where I'm wrong...

Comment: Your answer is not very "fair" for the select. The Enumerable.Range(0, n), ToArray() etc will cost extra time! Using constants is much faster! Look my answer for details about select and the functionality of LINQ.

Comment: @Knasterbax, why do you use c#? As oldschool programmer you have to prefer Assembler.

Answer (score 3):

The `for` way will be faster! Because there will not be any LINQsided expression tree evaluation/optimization etc...

But the real profit you have from using a `select` is the "Deferred Execution".

The `for` loop will be excuted instantly when the program pointer is at the section of the code where the `for` is placed. The `select` statement will only be executed when needed and just in the moment when it is needed.

Comment: I think his example is little bit fake, in this case he doesn't even defer execution because of ToArray().

Comment: Look at my comment at the main post ;)

Comment: With Linq to Objects (`IEnumerable<T>`) there's no expression tree evaluation